# Sorting and Paging A Collection With Unique IDs in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql

Ok, so I've been reading and reading and searching and searching and strangely it doesn't seem like my scenario has been really covered anywhere.

I have an app that creates a list of products. I want a simple view that can sort the products and page through them.

Fore reference here is a simple representation of the data in Firebase.

```
app
   stock
       unique_id
           name
           url
           imageUrl
           price
```

When creating the list I have multiple threads using the `push` method on my firebase references:

```
new Firebase(firebaseUrl).child('stock').push({
  name: "name",
  price: 123
});
```

This gives me a lovely "hash" collection on the `stock` property of the app.

So what I'd now like to do is have a table to sort and page through the records that were placed in the `stock` hash.

I make a GET request to my server to a url like `/stock?limit=10&skip=10&sort=name%20asc`. This particular url would be the second page where the table contained 10 records per page and was sorted by the `name` property in ascending order.

Currently in my query handler I have this:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl).child('stock');

if (this.sortDesc) {
  firebaseRef = firebaseRef
    .orderByChild(this.sortProperty)
    .endAt()
    .limitToFirst(this.limitAmount);
} else {
  firebaseRef = firebaseRef
    .orderByChild(this.sortProperty)
    .limitToFirst(this.limitAmount);

  if (this.skipAmount > 0) {
    firebaseRef = firebaseRef.startAt(this.skipAmount);
  }
}

firebaseRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
  var results = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    results.push(childSnapshot.val());
  });
  callback(null, results);
});
```

I'm running into a couple of problems. I'm going to split this into two cases, ascending and descending queries.

**Ascending query**

The `orderByChild` and `limitToFirst` seems to work correctly in the sorting ascending case. This means I can change which property has an ascending sort and how many results to return. What I am not able to get to work is skipping `n` records for paging to work. In the example query above I'm going to the second page. I do not get results 11-20, but I instead get the same 10 records as the first page.

**Descending query**

In this case I cannot begin to figure out how to tell Firebase to order by a property of the object identified by the unique key in a descending fashion. The closest I've read is to use `endAt()` and then `limit`. Docs say the `limit` is deprecated plus this still doesn't help me with any paging.

I tired to do doodles picturing how this would work. I came up with: order by the property, start at the 'end' of the collection, and then limit back to the page size. While this still wouldn't solve paging I would expect it to give me the last `n` records where `n` was the size of the page. I get no results.

I suppose I could say use `firebaseRef = firebaseRef        .orderByChild(this.sortProperty).limitToLast(this.limitAmount + this.skipAmount);` and in the result callback use the `forEach` loop to take the first (or would it be the last; I'm not sure how that iteration would work) `n` records where `n=this.limitAmount`. This just seems inefficient. Wouldn't it be better to limit the query instead of using CPU cycles to limit data that had come over the wire or is this the relational DB query thought pattern overriding the correct thought process for NoSQL?

**Further Confusion**

After posting this I've still been working on a solution. I've had some things get close, but I'm also running into this filtering issue. How could I filter a set of items to one property by still sorting on another? Jeez! I want to have the ability for a user to get all the stock that isn't sold out and order it by price.

**Finally**

Why hasn't this basic example been fleshed out on any of the Firebase "Getting Started" pages? Being able to show tabular data, page through it, sort, and filter seem like something that **EVERY** web developer would come across. I'm using ng-table in an Angular app to drive the view, but it still seems that regardless of platform that the queries that I'm trying to generate would be practical on any platform that Firebase supports. Perhaps I'm missing something! Please educate me!

**Firebase and NoSQL**

I've come up with this simple scenario that I often run into with web applications. I want to show tabular data, filter, page, and sort it. Very simple. Very common. Writing a SQL statement for this would be dead easy. Why is the query so complicated for something like Firebase. Is this common with all NoSQL solutions? There is no relational data being stored thus the need for a relational database seems unnecessary. Yet, it seems like I could hack together a little flat file to do this storage since the ability to make Firebase do these simple tasks is not made clear in its API or Docs. **FRUSTRATED!!!**

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question without providing any comment to as why it isn't a good question? I understand there is a bit of a rant to it, but seriously, if someone can't explain a question which boils down to "How to Page, Sort, and Filter a Tabular Data Set in Firebase" is a bad question then why bother with a driveby downvote?